# Adapt Qt window form to prebuilt QWindow

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm testing a project I've downloaded that doesn't have a "mainwindow.ui" but the main window is created programmatically inheriting QWindow instead.

```
OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow(QScreen* screen ): QWindow(screen)
```

It works properly but of course adding new elements on this window is not as quick as it would be using the Qt designer. Therefore I was wondering if there is a way, after creating a new form with the Qt designer, to promote the new window to this existing OpenGLWindow so that I can view its content in the "newwindow.ui".  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but this general idea should work, assuming the window class you created is named NewWindow:

```
class OpenGLWindow : public QWindow {
    Ui::NewWindow *ui; // Add this variable
    /* rest of class */
}

#include <ui_newwindow.h>
OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow(QScreen* screen): QWindow(screen), ui(new Ui::NewWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    /* rest of constructor */
}
```

And then don't forget to delete `ui` in the destructor.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion!
Unfortunately i have an error while compiling `ui->setupUi(this)` inside OpenGLWindow constructor. To be precise it is  : **no matching function for call to 'Ui::NewWindow::setupUi(OpenGLWindow*)'ui->setupUi(this); **. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. It seems like only QWidgets support the Qt Designer forms ([documentation here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#details)). Maybe you could change the inheritance from QWindow to QMainWindow? Sorry, this doesn't seem like a super easy fix :/

Comment: No worries, the problem is that almost all the methods inside OpenGLWindow, which is a quite long and complex class, work only if inheriting from QWindow. Thank you anyway!